# Adobe audition 2021 unusable with folder with lot of files

Tags: windows, windows-7, audio, windows-explorer, adobe-audition

I am a big user of Adobe Audition 1.5, and I'm mainly working with small sound effects files merging thems togethers for commercials spot.

I'm dealing with quite big folders, even if they are low in disk size, they contain a lot of short audio files (~4000).

My issue is that I need to quickly explore and "previsualize/play the start" of the files very quickly. On Adobe Audition 1.5 when I open the "import file" window, it open a windows explorer with an "automatic play file" option, and my largest folder and content is opened almost instantaneously.

My issue is that when using latest audition version (2021) the media explorer changed the way files import is handled. Now, Audition try to load the whole folder inside his media explorer interface and take very long to do it (several minutes).

Does anyone know a plugin or some solution to restore the old behavior. Or even some plugin for Windows explorer who would allow me to "autoplay" files when I'm clicking on it in the list ?